# Two dates look equal but they're not?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare two dates on two different sheets.  They both look the same, and match when decomposed into hours/minutes/etc., but when I test whether or not the contents of the cells are equal, the formula returns false.

This formula:

```
=AND(YEAR(J2)=YEAR('Uploaded Data'!J2),MONTH(J2)=MONTH('Uploaded Data'!J2),
DAY(J2)=DAY('Uploaded Data'!J2),HOUR(J2)=HOUR('Uploaded Data'!J2),
MINUTE(J2)=MINUTE('Uploaded Data'!J2),SECOND(J2)=SECOND('Uploaded Data'!J2))
```

returns "TRUE", while

```
=J2='Uploaded Data'!J2
```

returns "FALSE".

this sheet: 6/4/2013 7:00:00 AM

Uploaded Data: 6/4/2013 7:00:00 AM

Any idea why they don't match in the second formula?

Comment: What are their numeric values? (Format the values as a number.). Are they the same? You could have some floating point differences in there.

Comment: Unable to reproduce this in Excel 2013.

Comment: @Cory, you're right, they're different: one is 41429.29, and the other is 41429.2916666667.

Comment: @pnuts, no, it wasn't.  it's actually `41429.29167`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comment that their numeric values are slightly different, you could instead compare the two dates as numeric values and look for a delta less than the value of approximately one second to see whether they are equal:

```
=ABS(J2-'Uploaded Data'!J2)<0.00001
```